# Twitter API GET error

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, twitter

I'm trying to get some simple search term to from twitter using the API GET but I keep getting an error. Can anyone see where I might be going wrong here?

The error that i'm getting looks like this:

> jquery.js:5620 GET
>   https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=bowery&callback=jQuery190024276804403583108_1504110377251&_=1504110377252

Thanks again,
Danny.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('doc ready!');

  $('#submit').click(function() {

    var search_term = {
      q: 'bowery'
    };
    console.dir(search_term);
    search(search_term);
  });

});

function search(search_term) {
  console.log('searching for ');
  console.dir(search_term);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?' + $.param(search_term),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
      console.dir(data);
    }
  })

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>NEW TWEETS</h1>
  <ol id="tweets">
  </ol>
  <a href="#" id="submit">get tweets</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to authenticate yourself with your api key

Comment: Just paste that url in the browser. It says {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}.

Comment: How do you authenticate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to authenticate yourself. The Twitter API docs has documentation [here](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only) on how to do so.

In your situation, you're going to have some trouble authenticating yourself securely. Since you're running browser-facing code, any user who inspects your code will be able to look at your credentials and use them for themselves.

I recommend looking up some examples on how to use the Twitter API for your needs. It won't be as simple as a single HTTP request and it most likely will require you to run some kind of application server.